# How to get CSS nav to have dropdown options. I have been trying for days but think theres something preset in my code which has countered it

Tags: html, css, dropdown

So with my site there are two navigation bars one which comes up at the top when full screen on a laptop, and another on smaller screens which comes up on the right hand side as a menu drop.

I have been able to get a perfect drop down on the smaller left hand menu, but it doesn't work for the other.

Just comes up with the button with nothing coming off it.

got my basic css layout from
Massively by HTML5 UP
html5up.net | @ajlkn
Free for personal and commercial use under the CCA 3.0 license (html5up.net/license)

```css
/* Nav */

#nav {
  color: #ffffff;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: flex;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s ease, opacity 1s ease;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s ease, opacity 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: -ms-transform 1s ease, opacity 1s ease;
  transition: transform 1s ease, opacity 1s ease;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.175);
  height: 4rem;
  line-height: 4rem;
  margin: -4rem auto 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 2rem 0 0;
  position: relative;
  width: calc(100% - 4rem);
  max-width: 72rem;
  z-index: 2;
}

#nav ul.divided li {
  border-top-color: #ffffff;
}

#nav ul.icons li a.icon:hover:before {
  color: #18bfef;
}

#nav ul.icons.alt li .icon:before {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px #ffffff;
}

#nav ul.icons.alt li a.icon:hover:before {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px #18bfef;
}

#nav input,
#nav select,
#nav textarea {
  color: #ffffff;
}

#nav a {
  color: #ffffff;
  border-bottom-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

#nav a:hover {
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  color: #18bfef !important;
}

#nav strong,
#nav b {
  color: #ffffff;
}

#nav h1,
#nav h2,
#nav h3,
#nav h4,
#nav h5,
#nav h6 {
  color: #ffffff;
}

#nav blockquote {
  border-left-color: #ffffff;
}

#nav code {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.075);
  border-color: #ffffff;
}

#nav hr {
  border-bottom-color: #ffffff;
}

#nav ul.links {
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: flex;
  -moz-flex-grow: 1;
  -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
  -ms-flex-grow: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  -moz-flex-shrink: 1;
  -webkit-flex-shrink: 1;
  -ms-flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 900;
  letter-spacing: 0.075em;
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#nav ul.links li a {
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out, color 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out, color 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out, color 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out, color 0.2s ease-in-out;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0 2rem;
}

#nav ul.links li a:hover {
  color: inherit !important;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}

#nav ul.links li.active {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

#nav ul.links li.active a {
  color: #1e252d;
}

#nav ul.links li.active a:hover {
  color: #18bfef !important;
}

#nav ul.icons {
  -moz-flex-grow: 0;
  -webkit-flex-grow: 0;
  -ms-flex-grow: 0;
  flex-grow: 0;
  -moz-flex-shrink: 0;
  -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
  -ms-flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {
  #nav {
    display: none;
  }
}

#dropdown-products {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

#menu-products:hover #dropdown-products {
  display: grid;
  visibility: visible;
  position: grid;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!-- Nav -->
<nav id="nav">
  <ul class="links">
    <li><a href="Main.html">Overview</a></li>
    <li><a href="Uni.html">University Projects</a></li>
    <li id="menu-products">
      <a href="ULOTC.html">ULOTC</a>
      <ul id="dropdown-products">
        <li class="active"><a href="ULOTC.html">What is ULOTC?</a></li>
        <li><a href="ULOTC_AB.html">First & Second Year</a></li>
        <li><a href="ULOTC_JUO.html">Third Year JUO</a></li>
        li><a href="ULOTC_AT.html">Fourth Year JUO AT</a></li>
    <li><a href="ULOTC_Events.html">Highlights</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="Workexp.html">Work Experience</a></li>
    <li><a href="Volunteering.html">Volunteering</a></li>
  </ul>

</nav>
```

Photo of it working on the side one and not on the top one are attached.

Any help is welcome.

Let me know if any other information is needed

**Side working:**

[image: Side working]

**Top not working:**

[image]

Comment: let me know if the rest of the code is needed. sorry pretty new to this

Comment: Elise, I just completed the snippet with your code but I don't see anything. It would be better if you could add the complete code so that we can see the same issue as you see, you can also make use of an external service like Codesandbox or similar.

Comment: No, @m4n0, using an external service is not ideal. Much better to use a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/2518285).